# Creating Filebeat configuration with Terraform

Tags: terraform, filebeat

I am trying to create a Filebeat configuration file after creating a instance with Terraform:

```
resource "local_file" "greylogIP" {
  content  = <<EOF
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: '$'{path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["${aws_instance.web.public_ip}:5014"]
  EOF
  filename = "filebeat.conf"
}
```

where I need to pass the `${aws_instance.web.public_ip}` variable to allocate the dynamic IP but some how Terraform is also trying to interpolate `path: '$'{path.config}/modules.d/*.yml` which is a part of the Filebeat configuration and throws an error.

How can I pass the `path: '$'{path.config}/modules.d/*.yml` as a string instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape a literal dollar (`$`) with a double dollar (`$$`).

The [interpolation documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html) covers this:

> You can escape interpolation with double dollar signs: $${foo} will be rendered as a literal ${foo}.

There's some further mention of it in the [template docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#inline-templates):

> Important: Template variables in an inline template (such as consul_address above) must be escaped with a double-$. Unescaped interpolations will be processed by Terraform normally prior to executing the template.