# How to have a literal string of ${something} in a template data file

Tags: terraform

I have a template file, that is creating a fluentd file and inserting various variables. I am now trying to include [this plugin](https://github.com/takus/fluent-plugin-ec2-metadata)  which expects to find its own variables in the config file. The problem is that Terraform defines a variable in a template like `${variable}` and this plugin expects to find its variables in the file as literal `${variable}`

How can I tell terraform to not interpolate a `${}` in a file, but to actually pass that entire string?

File Snippet:

```
<filter tomcat.logs>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    customer ${customer}
    environment ${environment}
    application ${application}
  </record>
</filter>
```

The above `${}` are all variables I have defined for my template. I now need to add a section like this.

```
  <record>
    hostname      ${tagset_name}
    instance_id   ${instance_id}
    instance_type ${instance_type}
    az            ${availability_zone}
    private_ip    ${private_ip}
    vpc_id        ${vpc_id}
    ami_id        ${image_id}
    account_id    ${account_id}
  </record>
```

Where all of those are *not* variables but how it actually needs to look in the rendered template. I tried swapping them to be like `$${account_id}`, but that just ends up rendering account_id in the file.

```
data "template_file" "app" {
  template = "${file("templates/${var.application}.tpl")}"

  vars {
    customer               = "${var.customer}"
    environment            = "${var.environment}"
    application            = "${var.application}"
  }
}
```

---

Here is a breakdown of what is happening.

```
In the user data I have "instance_type $${instance_type}"  
The launch    configuration that is created for the instances, shows "instance_type    ${instance_type}"  
The actual file that is present on AWS shows    "instance_type"
```

Comment: What does your `data "template_file" "x" {}` resource look like?  What `vars` are you passing in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Filebeat configuration with Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971666/creating-filebeat-configuration-with-terraform)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That is for an inline template, Ive added more to my post to show its not an inline template.  The escaping doesnt seem to behave the same way.

Comment: @JustinSeiser I've retracted my vote. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373279/7296893) for some context, your question has been raised as a duplicate on meta. Feel free to leave the same comment there.

Comment: @JustinSeiser I'm not sure what you're seeing as not working but you do need to escape the dollars in template files as well as inline templates.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  Im adding more info to the post to explain whats happening here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  The answer from the marked duplicate question is incorrect for this instance.

template.tpl contains

```
cat <<EOT > /root/test.file
db.type=${db_type}
instance_type \$${instance_type}
EOT
```

Result

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.autoscaling_connect.data.template_file.app: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.autoscaling_connect.data.template_file.app: data.template_file.app: failed to render : 27:16: unknown variable accessed: bogus_value
```

---

template.tpl contains

```
cat <<EOT > /root/test.file
db.type=${db_type}
instance_type \$${instance_type}
EOT
```

Results in a launch configuration containing

```
cat <<EOT > /root/test.file
db.type=mysql
instance_type \${instance_type}
EOT
```

Results in the File we created on the instance containing

```
db.type=mysql
instance_type ${instance_type}
```

In Short to end up with a `${something}` in the file created from a terraform template file, you have to use `\$${something}` in the .tpl file.

Comment: I suspect this have changed in my case I had to switch to \${something}. We are on tf 12

Comment: Justin Seiser, thanks for your solution, worked like charm. @David Karlsson, you answers produces a different output. In a tftpl file, I get the following.
SOMETHING = "my value" 
1. `echo "\$${SOMETHING}"` produces  `${SOMETHING}` 
2. `echo "\${SOMETHING}"` produces `my value`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, having this issue inside a `resource`, the value is inside quotes and I don't need the `\` to fix it.

```
somevalue = "$${variable}"
```

produces `"${variable}"` instead of `"my_value"`