# Use templatefile in Terraform on AWS policy which uses IAM policy variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file, aws-policies

I am trying to build a cloud infrastructure in AWS using Terraform. I want to add a policy for a S3 bucket which uses attribute based authorization (ABAC) via the `templatefile` function of terraform. My problem is that the variable syntax used by terraform and AWS is the same (`${...}`).

Here is the policy template:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadRole1",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${bucketName}/*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "s3:ExistingObjectTag/myid": "${aws:PrincipalTag/myid}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The relevant part of the terrafrom file is:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "mybuckets-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybuckets[count.index].bucket
  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/bucket-policy.json", {
    bucketName = aws_s3_bucket.mybuckets[count.index].bucket
  })
  count = 2
}
```

So what I want is that the `${bucketName}` part of the template gets replaced by terraform, while keeping the AWS expression `${aws:PrincipalTag/user-id}` in place.
But running terraform on the configuration above causes the error message

> Call to function "templatefile" failed: ./bucket-policy.json:14,49-50: Extra
>   characters after interpolation expression; Expected a closing brace to end the
>   interpolation expression, but found extra characters..

If I put another item `${foobar}` in my template without a specifiying a value for it the error message is

> Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "foobar",
>   referenced at ./bucket-policy.json:11,30-36.

How can I make terraform do a partial evaluation of a template file while leaving all other items intact?

Comment: Have you considered just putting your policy in a HEREDOC instead? It's normally much simpler in these cases. Also your current example has stripped the `aws:PrincipalTag` part so it's not a meaningful example right now (there's nothing AWS specific using the same interpolation syntax). You can also escape $ interpolation from Terraform by doubling $ so use `$${...}`

Comment: I fixed the policy example.

Comment: Did you try escaping the `${aws:PrincipalTag/myid}` with `$${aws:PrincipalTag/myid}`?

Comment: Yes, that works well. Thank you.
If you post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: If that was the issue then it's a duplicate. I'll see if I can find the duplicate to close it as a target tot hat for others who stumble across this question and not the other.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/51971726/2291321 is a duplicate. If you agree let me know and I'll mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I agree @ydaetskcoR

Comment: @ydaetskcoR next time just change the dupe target like this; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the/355667?r=SearchResults&s=3|0.0000#355667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example above the syntax ${} will cause Terraform to try and evaluate the field as an interpolation function. Since u want to use this value literally and not as an interpolation function this will need to be double-escaped by using two $ symbols.

`$${aws:PrincipalTag/user-id}`

Comment: While this solution works fine, I would still prefer one where I could prevent those field from beeing interpreted within terraform, without having to alter the policy file.